# #[AxiosError: Request failed with status code 403] in React-Native while using physical device

Tags: linux, react-native, axios, http-status-code-403

P.S. I am using physical device due to RAM issue in my system. My system hangs when I run an emulator.

I am using RedmiNote9 pro max and code is running on Linux OS.

My backend is running on Nodejs in port 3000 and when I run.
http://192.XXX.XXX.XX:3000/user/login/email (my router ip) or http://localhost:3000/user/login/email in postman it is working fine. I am getting response as expected.

But when I try to run the same API endpoint in axios post request it is giving me Axios Network error or:

> AxiosError: Request failed with status code 403 error.

I tried mapping port 3000 with my physical device using adb reverse tcp:3000 tcp:3000, but still no use.

I tried using 10.0.0.2 (I know it is for emulator but at this point I am more of like what is harm in trying this) instead of localhost but still of no use.

this is API call

```
> axios({
>       method: 'post',
>       url: 'http://192.XXX.XXX.XX:3000/user/login/email',
>       headers: {
>         "Content-Type": "application/json",
>       },
>       data: {
>           "email":email,
>           "password":password
>       }
>     }).then((response) => {
>         console.log(response);
>         // console.log(response.status);
>     }).catch((e) => {
>         // console.log(e.response.status);
>         console.log("ERROR:", e);
>     })
```

Comment: Issue resolved, i just had to forward port 8080 to listen to 3000. It was somehow not working.

I used this command to do the same:

sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp --dport 8080 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3000